# Translate a word in a responsive menu

Tags: menus, responsive, language

The responsive menu of my web has a word in english: "back" and I have to translate it in Spanish: "atrás". Well, I'm not able to find the word to translate. It's not included in the pot file (language file) and the menu is not a plugin (or I think it's not).
The URL of my web: https://www.editorialufv.es/
And this is the screenshot with the word "back"[image]

Comment: Its jQuery dlmenu its in the file https://www.editorialufv.es/wp-content/themes/e-book-store/framework/include/frontend_assets/dl-menu/jquery.dlmenu.js?ver=1.0 line 72